# "Newest" page not updating

Tags: bug, status-completed

The "newest" page on the main site is currently not updating for me. It previously displayed a question about 10 minutes old, which I answered, but after refreshing the newest page the question has disappeared, and the newest question is now 45 minutes old. By going directly to my answer I have confirmed that the question still exists (it has not been deleted). I confirmed in chat that at least one other user is having this problem. Is this universal?

**Edit:** It seems this is also happening on meta, although right now only this question is affected. Currently on the main site, the last question visible on the newest page is #387332, but a dozen or so new questions have been asked since. At the time of this writing the most recent was [#387349](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387349/eigen-values-of-l2-projection-matrix).

**Edit 2:** Both newest pages are now working for me again. At least 22 questions on the main site were affecting, with the bug persisting for at least 90 minutes.

Comment: The question [Lack of activity](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6152/49437) describes a similar phenomenon. The given reason involved a database migration. Perhaps something like that happened this time, too.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the link. If the SE devs confirm this, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a brief hiccup with our service that provides these question lists - everything should be fine now.

Comment: Also, thanks for reporting it :)

Comment: Thanks for solving it! :)